# lib linking-error in just one target XCode 6.2

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I'm having trouble with one of my XCode Targets. I've got production- and a debug-target. I can run my production-Target but when I try to run the debug-target I get the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-AFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using cocoapods have the same target-settings for the Library search paths. 
I have no clue to find what could possibly be wrong. Trying to remove the cocoapod workspace and resetup didn't fix it. Cleaning and removing the derived data neither.

Comment: I have the same issue. Just started happening with xcode 6.2

Comment: We are having the same issue here on multiple projects. Start to happened on Xcode 6.2

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, with Xcode 6.2 the `libPods.a` were not included anymore in the  "*Linked Frameworks and Librairies*". I found it as the building process was perfectly fine with the Alpha target and not with the Beta one.

[image]

Moreover, be sure that your `Library Search Path` is correctly set:

```
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = (
    "$(inherited)"
);
```

Comment: so what is the solution for the libPods.a issue